# How to make pasted text to be slashed?

Tags: phpstorm

In  PhpStorm 2021
Having code like

```
\Log::info(  varDump($, ' -1 ::') );
```

when I want to paste text with “'”, like

```
$nextLoadedHostelImage['path']
```

I got invalid line if I paste this text inside of other “'”

```
\Log::info(  varDump($, ' -$nextLoadedHostelImage['path']::') );
```

Are there some options pasted text to be slashed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. `PHP | Escape symbols on paste in string literals` -- make sure it's enabled.

[image]